Serialising JSON consts as enums into C#
I am writing a C# program to import JSON data in the form of this JSON schema. The authors of this schema have chosen to implement some enumeration types as anyOf arrays of objects with const string properties like so:
  "ApplicationType": {
  "$id": "#ApplicationType",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "const": "Consent to make small (minor material) changes to a project with Planning Permission",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "const": "amendment.minorMaterial",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "value",
        "description"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    },
    {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "const": "Consent to make small (non-material) changes to a project with Planning Permission",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "const": "amendment.nonMaterial",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "value",
        "description"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    },

and
  "FileType": {
  "$id": "#FileType",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "const": "Elevations - existing",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "const": "elevations.existing",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "value",
        "description"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    },
    {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "const": "Elevations - proposed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "const": "elevations.proposed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "value",
        "description"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    },

NJsonSchema imports these as objects with writeable string properties and does not import the const values. I would like to import these const values so that I can validate and import the data. I have come up with three solutions but I am not particularly happy with any of them.
Importing as enums
I could import the above as the following annotated enums:
enum EApplicationType
{
    [Code("amendment.minorMaterial")]
    ConsentToMakeSmallMinorMaterialChangesToAProjectWithPlanningPermission,
    [Code("amendment.nonMaterial")]
    ConsentToMakeSmallNonMaterialChangesToAProjectWithPlanningPermission,

and
enum EFileType
{
    [Code("elevations.existing")]
    ElevationsExisting,
    [Code("elevations.proposed")]
    ElevationsProposed,

The advantage of this is each list has its own type, but the drawback is that any conversion has to use reflection, and to iterate through all values uses a lot of reflection. I could get around this by loading a dictionary once.
Using Classes and String Properties
I could import the values as strings on classes:
static class ApplicationType
{
    public static string ConsentToMakeSmallMinorMaterialChangesToAProjectWithPlanningPermission => "amendment.minorMaterial";
    public static string ConsentToMakeSmallNonMaterialChangesToAProjectWithPlanningPermission => "amendment.nonMaterial";

and
static class FileType
{
    public static string ElevationsExisting => "elevations.existing";
    public static string ElevationsProposed => "elevations.proposed";

The advantage here is simplicity, we will simply be comparing strings, however this will not ultimately be typed, we will be passing strings instead of the parent type. Also enumerating through all values will require reflection again.
Using Classes/Objects
Another option is to use whole objects as the JSON schema does, like so:
public class ConsentToDisplayAnAdvertisement : IApplicationType
{
    public string Description => "ConsentToDisplayAnAdvertisement";
    public string Value => "advertConsent";

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return Value.CompareTo((obj as IApplicationType).Value);
    }

}

or
public static class EEApplicationType
{
    public static DescriptionValue ConsentToMakeSmallChangesToAProjectWithPlanningPermission = new DescriptionValue
    (
        "ConsentToMakeSmallChangesToAProjectWithPlanningPermission",
        "amendment"
    );

While this mostly works it isn't straight forward using switch statements with objects and again need reflection to iterate through all values.
Is there a better way to do this that I've missed?

Corvus.JsonSchema supports the const values and gives you a Match() function to switch over them.
https://corvus-oss.org/

Thanks for the suggestion and your help. Unfortunately this doesn't seem practical in my case as the tool generates 22k units for this schema, ApplicationType generates 1k7 by itself!
